EEA real time data availability
I would like to ask if there is any way to get the real time pollutants concentrations via a downloadable file or an api from EEA (European Environmental Agency).
https://www.eea.europa.eu/en
EEA has a mobile application with real time data for basic pollutants, thus I am sure that EEA has early access to the data.
The city that is the most interested for me is Thessaloniki in Greece.
Thanks,
Dimitris
